# Converting list to numpy array issues

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

Using python xy's spyder code editor.

When saving a list of pixel color values to a numpy array using np.asarray(list), it gives me an array with weird dimensions.

The dimensions of the original image being read is (864,1089) (width,height) and is a JPEG image.  When converting this list to a numpy array, it returns an array with dimensions (940896, 3), when I expected a one dimensional array with dimensions (940896,).  I don't understand where the 3 came from...

```
img = Image.open('Images\satellite6.jpg')
pix = img.load()
width = img.size[0]
height = img.size[1]
pixels = []

for j in range(height):
    for i in range(width):
        pixels.append(pix[i,j])

pixels = np.array(pixels)
print np.shape(pixels)
```

(940896, 3)

I am also new to posting questions, so if anything seems unclear, let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to see what `pix[0,0]` contains for example:

```
>>> img = Image.open('./edgewalker-cat.png')
>>> pix = img.load()
>>> pix
<PixelAccess object at 0x7f1afac932f0>
>>> pix[0,0]
(0, 0, 0)
```

Its tuple, size of 3, so the `pixels` list, you are constructing one by one item, will be converted to the dimension of (width*height, 3).

**UPD:** On grayscaled images, you'll get a plain int value:

```
>>> img = Image.open('./urban-dove-gray.jpg')
>>> pix = img.load()
>>> pix[0,0]
31
```

Comment: pix[0,0] returns (255,255,255).  What I don't understand is that I've done this with other images and it's always returned an array with one dimension.  Is it because it's a bigger image?

Comment: Don't think the size matters. You probably did it before with grayscaled images. Try to see the result of pix[0,0] on grayscale image - it will give you a single int.